# Is it okay to recite hadith during prayer?

Tags: salat, hadith

It seems ordinary to recite Qur'an versus and make dua during prayer.  But I've never seen anyone suggest reciting hadith during prayer, which makes me think it's inappropriate.

There may be a good reason not to (e.g., because we worship Allah and not his Prophet).  Or maybe the style of hadith is not suited to recitation during prayer.  However, these are just guesses.

**Question**: Is it okay to recite hadith during prayer?

I don't seem to get anything helpful by searching for `recite hadith during prayer` in e.g. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=recite%20hadith%20during%20prayer), [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=recite%20hadith%20during%20prayer).

Comment: Ahadith are sayings, actions etc of the Prophet. There will be no need to say them in salah as they have nothing to do with salah

Comment: Anyway why would you say a Hadith in salah. One Hadith is 'Do get angry'. You wouldn't say that in salah. Salah is to worship Allah so nothing else should be said apart from the Surahs and duas you have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Salah, it should be performed in the strict manner ordained by the Prophet Muhammad(p.b.u.h) and only the prescribed verses should be recited at the prescribed times.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Pray as you have seen me praying." 
>   [**Sahih Bukhari, Book 10, Hadith 28**](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/28)

Any Quranic verses (and only Quranic verses) may be recited after the Fatiah and before the Rukuh(bowing down). There is no evidence for the Prophet reciting Hadith within the Salah so we don't do that. In matters of obligatory religious rituals and practices anything that the Prophet didn't do is considered an innovation(Bid'ah) and is sinful.

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, “He who innovates something in this
>   matter of ours (i.e., Islam) that is not of it will have it rejected
>   (by Allah).” [Bukhari & Muslim] In another version in Muslim it reads:
>   “He who does an act which we have not commanded, will have it rejected
>   (by Allah).” **[Fourty Hadith Nawawi 5](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/5)**

Furthermore there is no evidence that reciting Hadith has any virtue in itself. Hadith are meant to only be studied for the teachings in them and the words themselves do not have any virtue attached to them.

On the other hand reciting Quranic verses in Prayer is proven from several sources, including the Quran itself:

> **Quran 73:20** Indeed, your Lord knows, [O Muhammad], that you stand [in prayer] almost two thirds of the night or half of it or a third of
>   it, and [so do] a group of those with you. And Allah determines [the
>   extent of] the night and the day. He has known that you [Muslims] will
>   not be able to do it and has turned to you in forgiveness, so recite
>   what is easy [for you] of the Qur'an. He has known that there will be
>   among you those who are ill and others traveling throughout the land
>   seeking [something] of the bounty of Allah and others fighting for the
>   cause of Allah. So recite what is easy from it and establish prayer
>   and give zakah and loan Allah a goodly loan. And whatever good you put
>   forward for yourselves - you will find it with Allah. It is better and
>   greater in reward. And seek forgiveness of Allah. Indeed, Allah is
>   Forgiving and Merciful.

And in Hadith:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: The Qur'an is recited in every prayer and in those prayers in which
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) recited aloud for us, we recite aloud in the
>   same prayers for you; and the prayers in which the Prophet (ﷺ) recited
>   quietly, we recite quietly. If you recite "Al-Fatiha" only it is
>   sufficient but if you recite something else in addition, it is better.
>   **[Sahih Bukhari, Book 10, Hadith 166](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/166)**
>
> Narrated Ibn Abbas: (My mother) Umu-l-Fadl heard me reciting "Wal
>   Mursalati `Urfan" (77) and said, "O my son! By Allah, your recitation
>   made me remember that it was the last Sura I heard from Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ). He recited it in the Maghrib prayer. **[Sahih Bukhari
>   Book 10, Hadith 157](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/157)**